# 2 Problems with Enabling Editable DataGridViewComboBox (not data bound) in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I am very new to C#, and I really am stuck. I will try to be concise.

I have some ComboBox (in the same column) in DataGridView, and I want users to be able to type in the ComboBox. I got it to semi-work...

*Problem 1:
When I type in it, even though what I typed is added to the list of selections in the drop down, the ComboBox goes blank and I have to re-select the value I just entered. How can I make it so the value I type stays as the selection and not go blank.

*Problem 2:
Is there a way I can make certain ComboBox not editable in the same column? My code seems to make all of my ComboBox user editable. How can I make some ComboBox exceptions?

Thanks in advance, so much, if you could help!

Here are the codes:

```
private void dm_dgview_add_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl combo = e.Control as    DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
                combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
                combo.TextChanged += new EventHandler(combo_TextChanged);
            }
        }

        void combo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dm_dgview_add.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);

        }

        private void dm_dgview_add_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = dm_dgview_add.CurrentCell as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;

            if (cell != null && e.ColumnIndex == dm_dgview_add.Columns[1].Index)
            {
                if (!cell.Items.Contains(e.FormattedValue) && e.FormattedValue != null)
                {
                    cell.Items.Add(e.FormattedValue);
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help, I greatly appreciate this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to set cell.Items.SelectedItem = e.FormattedValue in the cell validating event?